# ValueError: int() base must be >= 2 and <= 36 but using 3 is invalid?

Tags: python

I'm a little bit confuse in using int(x, [base]). Can someone explain why it keeps throwing this error? Sorry, im just starting to learn the basics.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#63>", line 1, in <module>

     int('23123',1)

ValueError: int() base must be >= 2 and <= 36  

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#75>", line 1, in <module>

int('123',3)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 3: '123'
```

Comment: If you want to decode a number in base 3, then the string has to be a base 3 number. Why do you think that `'123'` **is** a base 3 number?

Comment: A number in base three can only contain `0`, `1` and `2`. Base three has only three possible digits. That's why it is base 3.

Comment: "Base 1" would be just counting fingers, `|||||` is 5, `||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||` is 30. Not a very useful base to be working in.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, now I remember how the base number works. Sorry for asking this noob question.
Base 3
0 1 2 10 11 12 20 21 21 22 . . . . . . . . 
   
ex: Base 7    
0 1 2 4 5 6 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 20 . . . . . . .. . . .

Comment: @deceze In base X, only digits 0…(X-1) are present. So in base 1, we'd only have the 0.

Comment: @glglgl Sure, but since base 1 is not a valid base in Python there is no real code which I could show, the choice of symbol is entirely arbitrary in this case, and I wanted to stick close to the "counting fingers" analogy.

Comment: @deceze My point was a different one: "counting fingers" is not base 1, it is a completely different mechanism. No matter how you choose the symbol, the sympol of choice would be of value 0, not of value 1.

Comment: @glglgl In base 1, each digit can only have one value, and it's irrelevant what that value is. It merely matters whether that digit is there or not. `000` is the same value as `|||` is the same value as ``. In this regard, it's exactly like counting fingers which you either raise (there) or don't (not there).

Answer (score 3):

The error is as it says: not the base is invalid, but the literal is invalid for the given base. In base 3, you only have the digits `0`, `1` and `2`, so `3` is an invalid digit.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand that the literal that cause the error.